# How to Detect Autosave Change Event With Word JavaScript APi

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

Does the Word JavaScript API support event detection for an autosave on or off event such as when autosave gets turned off for a document issue?

I can see Excel supports it as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events

Answer (score 0):

If the API you refer to is Word WAC API, I'd say no. The Event on WAC is a part of recent works and will be released progressively. However we can't give out an explicit timeline of it for now.
Thanks.